# Fluid MovieClip with mouse pan at AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In fact, all I want to have is getting this pan effect and to be able to add buttons inside fluidly resizing main MovieClip.

See this example:  [www.avmevsimifilm.com](http://www.avmevsimifilm.com)

Do you have a good idea to make something working like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Parallax scrolling for the parallax effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling)

and the "fluid" pan effect is probably just:

```
smoothCoeficitent = 0.2;
x = x + (targetX-x)*smoothCoeficient;
```

where targetX would be some future position based on mouseX (say targetX = mouseX; or similar);